# Form control not found

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I've created this form inside `ngOnInit()` method:

```
this.cardForm = this.fb.group({
    card_number: ['', Validators.required],
    holderName: ['', Validators.required],
    expiry: ['', Validators.required],
    cvc: ['', Validators.required],
    address_line1: ['', Validators.required],
    address_line2: ['', Validators.required],
    address_city: ['', Validators.required],
    address_state: ['', Validators.required],
    address_zip: ['', Validators.required],
    address_country: ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

On my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cardnumber">Card number</label>
    <input 
      type="text"
      name="cardnumber"
      class="input-transparent form-control"
      formControlName="card_number"
      data-mask="9999-9999-9999-9999"
      placeholder="____-____-____-____"
      required="required">
 </div>
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'card_number'

Comment: Is `this.fb.group` a `FormGroup` ? Where is it initiated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `id` in your `input` tag.
Try to insert

```
<input
    id="card_number"
   ...
>
```

Update 1
If you could provide some more code that would help a lot. Since there is a Validators.required it should have a value. Anyways, just a hunch
try to use this on your input.

`[formControl]="cardForm.controls['card_number']"`

instead of

`formControlName="card_number"`

Comment: I thought it's only necessary to set the `formControName`, isn't it?

Comment: The message is not shown now. Nevertheless, the value is not picked up. See on post.

Comment: @user3227319 actually it's seemed weird that it has no value because you have a Validator.required for that formcontrol. I'll try to edit my answer

Comment: @user3227319 have you resolve your errors? glad to help

Answer (score 0):

call:

```
 this.cardForm = this.fb.group({...)}
```

in constructor, instead of ngOnInit()

Comment: try:  this.cardform = new FormGroup({..}), inside constructor, instead of ngOnInit()